# Mapping a result set (of two integers) in mybatis?

Tags: java, sql, database, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have the following stored procedure - simply returning two integers for now :

```
USE [DB_NAME_HERE]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[PR_PROCEDURE_NAME]
SELECT 0 AS ValueA,0 AS ValueB
```

and I have the following mapper XML :

```
  <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.companyname.service.mybatis.model.modelClass">
    <result column="ValueA" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="valueA" />
    <result column="ValueB" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="valueB" />
  </resultMap>

  <select id="getPurgedTokens" resultMap="BaseResultMap" statementType="CALLABLE">
      {call PR_PROCEDURE_NAME(
          #{resultContainer.valueA, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER},
          #{resultContainer.valueB, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}
      )}
  </select>
```

Then I have the following java class for the mapping :

```
public class modelClass implements Serializable {

    private int valueA;
    private int valueB;

    public int getValueA() { return this.valueA; }
    public void setValueA(int valueA) { this.valueA = valueA; }

    public int getValueB() { return this.valueB; }
    public void setValueB(int valueB) { this.valueB= valueB; }
}
```

But when I run up my application, and attempt to get any kind of data, I get the following error :

```
code=DataIntegrityViolationException,messages=[SqlSession operation; SQL []; Invalid JDBC call escape at line position 10.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid JDBC call escape at line position 10., Invalid JDBC call escape at line position 10.]]
```

All help here is greatly appreciated - I have been trying to get this working for days!

EDIT : UPDATE WITH EXACT COPIES OF LATEST CODE!

### MapperXML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
    <mapper namespace="com.company.product.mybatis.mappers.MapperXML">

    <!-- Commented out the base result map because now we link directly in the paramter type? -->

    <!--
    <resultMap id="BaseResultMap" type="com.companyname.service.mybatis.model.modelClass">
    <result column="ValueA" javaType="java.lang.Integer" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="valueA"/>
    <result column="ValueB" javaType="java.lang.Integer" jdbcType="INTEGER" property="valueB"/>
  </resultMap>-->

  <!-- -------------------------------------------- -->

  <select id="getPurgedTokens" parameterType="com.companyname.service.mybatis.model.ModelClass" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call PR_TokenPurge_Clean(
      #{dvalueA, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER},
      #{valueB, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}
    )}
  </select>
</mapper>
```

### ModelClass

```
package com.companyname.service.mybatis.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class ModelClass implements Serializable {

    private int valueA;
    private int valueB;


    public int getVavlueA() { return this.valueA; }
    public void setValueA(int valueA) { this.valueA = valueA; }

    public int getValueB() { return this.valueB; }
    public void setValueB(int valueB) { this.valueB = valueB; }
}
```

### DAO

```
package com.company.product.dao.mybatis;

[imports (removed for brevity and security)...]


@Repository
public class ModelClassDaoMybatis implements ModelClassDao {

    private TokenPurgeModelMapper tokenPurgeModelMapper;
    private SqlSessionOperations sqlSessionOperations;

    @Override
    public TokenPurgeModel purgeTokens()
    {
        if (this.sqlSessionOperations.selectOne(".getPurgedTokens") != null)
        {
            System.out.println("I FOUND A VALUE!!!!!!");
            return (TokenPurgeModel) sqlSessionOperations.selectOne(testing);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No value found for select statement");
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<TokenPurgeModel> getPurgedTokens() {
        return tokenPurgeModelMapper.getPurgedTokens();
    }

    @Required
    public void setTokenPurgeModelMapper(final TokenPurgeModelMapper tokenPurgeMapper) {
        this.tokenPurgeModelMapper = tokenPurgeMapper;
    }
    @Required
    public void setSqlSessionOperations(SqlSessionOperations sqlSessionOperations) {
        this.sqlSessionOperations = sqlSessionOperations;
    }
}
```

### MODEL MAPPER CLASS

```
package com.company.product.mybatis.mappers;


[imports (removed for brevity and security)...]

public interface TokenPurgeModelMapper {

    // This is the one I am using right now. (as seen in the DAO!)
    TokenPurgeModel purgeTokens();

    // Get the list of tokens which have been removed from the PAN table.
    List<TokenPurgeModel> getPurgedTokens(); // This is actually never used - will be used in later funcationality!
}
```

THANKS for looking at this for me!

Comment: You need to call the store procedure from Mybatis like below:

     {call PR_PROCEDURE_NAME()}

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, first thing is to use syntax `{call PR_PROCEDURE_NAME()}`

Then it depends on how the procedure is written and on which SGBD is used.
There are multiple possibilities including:

Return the values as procedure OUT parameters:

```
<select id="getPurgedTokens" parameterType="com.companyname.service.mybatis.model.modelClass" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call PR_PROCEDURE_NAME(
        #{valueA, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER},
        #{valueB, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}
    )}
</select>
```

The *modelClass* parameter does not actually provide input parameters in this case and is used here just as target container for OUT parameters; and then you don't need *resultMap*.

If the result becomes more complex, return a cursor on the select:

```
{call PR_PROCEDURE_NAME(
    #{resultContainer.resultList, mode=OUT, jdbcType=CURSOR, javaType=java.sql.ResultSet, resultMap=BaseResultMap}
)}
```

Or a function (instead of a procedure) returning the cursor fetching the Select (some SGBD may allow writing just the SELECT in the body), then merely:

```
SELECT function_name from DUAL
```

bound with the *resultMap*

Comment: Sorry for taking ages to reply to your suggestion! I had some really bad news recently and had to take some time away. I will be trying this today! :)

Comment: Hey @blackwizard - Your suggestion seems to have helped a little - but I now get the following error : 


    Procedure PR_TokenPurge_Clean has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

I assume this is because I am now using the OUT parameters? is there something I need to do to facilitate them?

Comment: Since I had proposed several solutions, can you add an edit to the question with a snippet of what you execute now?

Comment: Edited to reflect current standing :)

Comment: The error I am getting at this point in time is : 

"There is no getter for property named &apos;resultContainer"

Comment: does it look like I failed to follow your suggestion correctly? Or is there something else at play here?

Comment: Sorry, I had note stated that my snipped came from my code using annotations and named parameter. In the XML here, the _resultContainer_ being the parameter you pass, you shall add the type as parameterType and then access directly to properties: #{valueA, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER}, there will be a getter for valueA.

Comment: Hey again, @blackwizard - I tried this, but I am still being told there is no setter for the property, I do see that I am getting the value back, because the error says : 

"Could not set property 'valueA' of 'class org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject$NullObject' with value '1' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'valueA' in 'class java.lang.Class'"

Comment: Hi, The error means you don't provide target for out parameter. Check my latest update. A copy/paste should be enough this time.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, @blackwizard - I did copy and paste it, and I still get the error :(

Comment: then I think you will have to post more of your code so that I find out where you are mistaking and/or what is not  that implicit for you and I'm not telling you

Comment: Will edit my main post now and see if we can get it working :) wont be long!

Comment: Hey again @blackwizard, thanks for sticking with me through this! I have added all of the code at the bottom of the original post! Thanks again, I hope its just something stupid that will be easy to fix.

Comment: Properties in _modelClass_ must be _deleteCount_, _totalCount_ (names referenced in mapper xml) instead of _valueA_, _valueB_. And I guess the error message actually states "There is no setter for property named 'deleteCount' [...]"

Comment: Hey again, blackwizard - I changed the mapper values to valueA and valueB in order to try and get them to match, but I still seem to be getting the same error.

One thing to note is that it says there is no setter in "java.lang.class", as opposed to in my actual ModelClass... Is that of interest?

Comment: pretty tough to almost blindly debug your code :p. and you are adding difficulty by adding typos in what you copy in your question(otherwise it would not work at all). You may fix typos: _**d**valueA_ in the mapper, _getVa**v**lueA_ in _ModelClass_,  _ .getPurgedTokens_ in Dao => remove leading dot from statement name 
Also try to change type from primitive `int` to object `Integer`, I won't bet on it, but one never knows.
New error gives me an intuition: rename the type ModelClass to Model for example, anyway remove the _Class_ expression from the name.

Comment: Why you call `session.selectOne("getPurgedTokens")` whereas you have a Mapper interface.
Do `ModelClass model = new ModelClass(); session.getMapper(TokenPurgeModelMapper.class).getPurgedTokens(model); model.getValueA();`
You actually never pass the parameter, where the OUT params should go?
And change the return type to void: even though you consider it as a select, because you get data from DB, it is not: you pass a "container" param to be filled by the procedure.